# how to make a database based templating engine without using eval php

Tags: php, mysql, eval, template-engine

I'm creating a CMS i want to save my templates in the database

for easily Adding , Editing and deleting templates

but the templates my contain a PHP code so my question is how to support templates that contain php code without using eval like expressionEngine .

Comment: It doesn't sound possible.  Using simple substitution, your question reads "How can I eval without using eval?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) which is a full templating engine that supports [sandboxing](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#sandbox-extension) which you could use to restrict the user created templates.